# Using css how so I create a pill shape which is circular on one side and angled on the other?

Tags: html, css

This is the shape I am trying to create:

[image: This is the shape I am trying to create]

This is what I have so far:

[image: so far]

This is my code:

```css
.pill-left {
      position: relative;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: #FDA725;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    
    .pill-right {
      position: relative;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: #CED2D9;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="pill-left">5
</div>
<div class="pill-right">10
</div>
```

The two issues I have is firstly how to display the text within the pill and not be rotated, the second is how to achieve the sloping line. I have tried a few things such as border-right: 50px. How can I achieve this? I suspect it is obvious but I can't get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could accomplish this with a linear-gradient background:

***A brief explanation***
a `linear-gradient` background colour handles both pill colours - setting the positions the same here (eg. 48% & 48%, then 52% & 52%) means there's no blend between them.

to get fully rounded corners we set `border-radius` to half the height of the element or greater - there's no harm in going larger, so 9999px just ensures it will always be more than the element height.

you don't necessarily need `display:flex` & `justify-content` in this instance, but it will ensure the percentages are aligned at both ends of the pill if you set a specific width for example.

```css
.split-pill {
  border-radius: 9999px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  background: linear-gradient(-70deg, #FDA725 48%, white 48%, white 52%, #CED2D9 52%);
}

.left {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.right {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="split-pill">
  <span class="left">10%</span>
  <span class="right">50%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one! Please explain why you use `border-radius: 9999px` (or post a reference link) as it will make little sense to many people, *tips & tricks category*.